# Save Data Between Screens

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an iPhone app with a form that has terms and conditions. When the user taps on the terms and conditions link, it brings them to another screen within the application that shows them.

Now, when they tap away and come back they lose all of the information they placed into the fields. Is there any way of saving this data in the forms short of storing everything in a dictionary when they leave and when the view reloads filling it back?

Comment: core data? it's not a big thing which needs to use core data but, Why not? it's their...Whenever you view looses focus you save current data to core data and when you call viewDidLoad just read it back from core data. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use a UIAlertView for the terms and conditions? I've used this in a few apps. Longer text automatically creates a scroll in the alert. This will keep you from needing to leave the screen at all.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have to use a WebView that loads an iPhone formatted site containing our terms and conditions (with links to other policies too).

Comment: Ok, the next question would be, can you use a modal view controller to display the UIWebView? This will prevent the user from leaving the form screen as well. When the UIViewController is dismissed, the form is still filled out behind it.

Comment: I am currently using a modal view controller but when I transition back to the form all of the information is gone.

Comment: Can you post some code? What are you doing in your viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear? Is it possible you're clearing the fields by force? I can provide code as well where I am using a form which does *not* clear after a modal view is dismissed. However, I am setting my fields up in loadView and not clearing them on willAppear or didAppear.

Comment: I was able to figure it out over the weekend. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have some way of saving that data when the user leaves the screen using a dictionary or some other means.  So the short answer is no.

A longer answer is that you could change how you are navigating to the new screens and prevent this screen from getting dumped when you move on.